# Can't add tags from android

Tags: bug, status-norepro, mobile-web

I can't add tags to a question while using the mobile version using the Android browser (I'm using 4.1)

Comment: What _does_ happen? Errors? Nothing?

Comment: Also please make sure that's not the *only* thing to fix in the post you're trying to edit. If there are more mistakes - spelling errors, grammatical errors, formatting errors - please fix them all in one go.

Comment: What happens is just the text of the tag appears. But if I try and post the question, it still says "You need to add at least one tag.."

Comment: I tried with Chrome and there wasn't any such issue.

Answer (score 1):

I can't replicate the behavior, in fact I've added the no-repro tag via chrome on Android.